# Create a chrome link that opens on multiple terminal servers

Tags: windows-server-2008, terminal-server, google-chrome

I've installed Chrome using the stand alone client and all users can see and access chrome. Now I'm trying to create a link and save it in a share for the end users to access.

I can only open the link on the server that I created it on. If I try to open it on a different server it'll launch chrome but only the default page.

Apparently Chrome is using the app-id tag with a hash that only works on the server that the link was created. How can I adjust this so the link will open on all servers?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you try creating a link using a destination as a parameter?

"C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe" "www.yahoo.com"

This works for me but does have the added issue of only working on 64-Bit machines (Because of the (x86))

Comment: That seems to have fixed it. I started googling it and saw the app-id issue and instantly thought it was harder to fix than it really was. Thanks!